# For... of loop turning objects undefined halfway through loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous

I have a JavaScript (Node.js) function that loops through an array of "listing" objects with a for... of loop (because it needs to wait for async stuff to finish) and passes them to another function to be posted. For some reason, given an array of around 3,000 listing objects, the for... of loop will successfully loop through around 2,200, and then turns the rest to undefined.

I've made sure the array passed to the function contains no undefined objects, and even gone as far as to listings.map() through the array and console.log each value RIGHT before the for... of loop begins. All objects in the array are defined until the for... of loop starts. I also have commented all code out of the for... of loop so it just logs each listing, and its still turning the last 1000 or so to undefined.

```
async function postAllItems(listings, limit, socket) {

  listings.map((item) => {
    console.log(typeof item);
  }); // Result: Logs all items as objects, correctly

  for (const item of listings) {
    console.log(typeof item); // still logs the last ~1000 as undefined
  } // Result: Logs first ~2000 items as objects, the rest are undefined

}
```

I can't figure out why the for... of loop is doing this!

Comment: Can you update your snippet such that it fully conforms to the guidance on creating a [mre]?

Comment: Without further context, it's hard to know why it's happening because it's not a normal behavior. I recommend you to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `All objects in the array are defined`  How are you confirming this?.

Comment: @Keith console.log(typeof item)

Comment: @technophyle I've update the code in my post to exactly what I have in my function right now. The `listings` passed to the function is just an array of objects fetched from an API. `listings.map` performs exactly as expected, `for (const item of listings)` starts logging `undefined` about half way through the loop.

Comment: mmm, that is strange.  The only other thing I can think is that `listings` implements a custom iterator, and it's buggy.  If you do -> `console.log(listings[Symbol.iterator].toString());` what does it say?

Comment: @Keith `function values() { [native code] }`

Comment: It's not that then... a bit of a mystery..  Are you able to knock up a really small `node.js` file demonstrating this?,  if you do -> `for (const item of [...listings]) { ...` do you get the same?

Comment: Maybe try to `console.log` `listings.length` right before the `for` statement and inside it.

Comment: This sounds like it's a sparse array. If you do something like `array = [1, 2, 3]; array.length = 10;` you'll get this kind of result.

Comment: @technophyle it logs the correct array length both before and during the for loop :(

Comment: Without the reproducible example, it's very difficult to debug it. Try to create one and we can take a look again.

Comment: Verify everything is defined with: `listings.every(item => typeof item !== 'undefined')` or better-yet: `listings.every(item => item != null && typeof item !== 'undefined')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out array.map ignores empty array values. So `[3,,,6,,8]` would just be `[3,6,8]`, while for... of reads them as undefined. A filtering function that runs earlier in the program was splicing elements out of the array but leaving them empty.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense glad you got it sorted.  `splicing elements out of the array`, interesting splicing doesn't leave empty elements normally.   I assume the earlier process was deliberately setting the element to undefined, and not splicing..

Comment: See [An adventure in sparse arrays](https://remysharp.com/2018/06/26/an-adventure-in-sparse-arrays).